# Expected to return a value in arrow function warning

Tags: javascript

this pice of code finds a user by id and if is user is not found it creates one but...

I´m getting the "Expected to return a value in arrow function  array-callback-return" warning

```
findUser(id)
    .then((user) => {
        if (user.empty) {
            return createUser()
                .then((user) => setUser(user));
        } else {
            const updatedUser = user.docs[0];
            return {
                id: updatedUser.id,
                ...updatedUser.data(),
            };
        }
    })
```

I can´t get rid of it and I´m not sure why is happening.
thanks! hope this piece of code helps you don´t want to see it all. is a mess :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not consistently returning a value from inside `findUser`'s `.then`. You should return the `createUser` call:

```
if (user.empty) {
  return createUser()
    .then
```

This is useful because it means that the resulting Promise chain will resolve when `createUser` and `setUser` finish. Otherwise, the `createUser` / `setUser` Promise will be disconnected from the outside - you won't be able to determine when it finishes, or handle its errors.

Note that you don't need an anonymous callback which calls `setUser` - you can pass the `setUser` function itself to the `.then`:

```
return createUser()
  .then(setUser);
```

You also might consider using `async` / `await`, the control flow will be clearer:

```
const user = await findUser(id);
if (user.empty) {
  const createdUser = await createUser();
  // no need to await below if setUser doesn't return a Promise
  await setUser(user);
} else {
  const updatedUser = user.docs[0];
  return {
    id: updatedUser.id,
    ...updatedUser.data(),
  };
}
```

Comment: `.then(setUser(user));` works. didn´t know that. cool! I also added the return but the warning is still showing. so is an issue with then() instead of async / await ? (I updated my example to show what I´ve tried.

Comment: Not `.then(setUser(user));`, but `.then(setUser);`

Comment: what kind of black magic is that... what is `.then(setUser)` doing? It works but why it works without passing data to the state?

Comment: Functions are first-class members in Javascript. You can define them anywhere and pass them around like any variable.

Comment: ok. good lesson learned thank you. but.. the warning is still visible. should I convert to async / await to get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure you're `return`ing the Promise, as in the first part of the answer?

Comment: Wait, you say the rule is `array-callback-return`, but you don't have any array methods in the code in the question, that doesn't make sense. Is that really the area where the linter warning is?